# How can I access a state variable using a string within functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access a state variable using a string within a React functional component.

For example, I know in Class components I can do the following to access state based on input:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputOne: null
    }}

   handleBlur(e, name) {
       if (!this.state[name]) {
         this.setState({
          [`${name}Missing`]: true,
        });
       } else {
       this.setState({
        [`${name}Missing`]: false,
      });
    }

    render() {
       <input onBlur={(e) => this.handleBlur(e, "inputOne")}></input>
   }
 }
```

By using `this.state[name]` within the `handleBlur` function, I can access the inputOne state value dynamically.

How would I do something similar within a functional component?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is too broad a question. Get some real code and try to do on something in codesandbox. Read up useState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Custom = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    inputOne: "",
  });

  const handleBlur = (e, name) => {
    if (!state[name]) {
      setState({
        [`${name}Missing`]: true,
      });
    } else {
      setState({
        [`${name}Missing`]: false,
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <input onBlur={(e) => handleBlur(e, "inputOne")}></input>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you Ali! This answer most closely resembles the structure of my app. Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in a functional component would be to have the same sort of state structure as in the class component - that is, for the state values you want to dynamically access, put them all into an object (or an array).

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
  inputOne: null
})
```

And then `const someStr = 'inputOne'` and `inputs[someString]` will give you that state value. To set it:

```
setInputs({
  ...inputs,
  [someStr]: newValue
  // or use whatever computed property name you want
});
```

It's usually recommended to use separate state variables when using functional components - but when you have *lots* of state variables that you want to dynamically access, using a single object or array can make more sense.

Comment: Thanks so much, definitely learned something new here!